# DirectoryNotFoundException error while copying the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am trying to develop a web application which will send a file to the server (in this case the server is a local one). However when I try to send the file, it always gives:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find part of the path.

I have verified that the folder actually exists. And to ensure, I create the Directory before copying but I still get the error. Could anyone help please?
Here is the code:

```
string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("c:\\test\\Sample.txt");
string SaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Uploadfile") + "\\";

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(SaveLocation))
{
     System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveLocation);
     System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\test\\Sample.txt", SaveLocation, true);
}
```

The value of `SaveLocation` is:

> C:\Users\Nerd\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Uploadfile\

Comment: What is th exact value of SaveLocation when you copy the file ?

Comment: It is : "C:\Users\Nerd\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Uploadfile\".

Comment: As an aside, it's often easier to write strings like these using this syntax `string directory = @"c:\test\Sample.txt";` to avoid having to use escape characters.

Comment: @David: I tried using that but to no avail.

Comment: @nerd Sorry, it wasn't an answer, just a pointer that can make strings more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `System.IO.File.Copy` needs its second argument to be a path to a file and not a path to a directory. Adjust your code to include the name you want the file to be saved.

```
string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("c:\\test\\Sample.txt");
string SaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Uploadfile") + "\\";

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(SaveLocation))
{
     System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SaveLocation);
     System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\test\\Sample.txt", SaveLocation + "Sample.txt", true);
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but it wouldn't give `DirectoryNotFoundException`, it should give `IOException'` with message `The target file "..." is a directory, not a file.`

Comment: @DavidG Indeed, the error message is not really helpful in this case